# How do I prevent facebook from displaying permissions.request dialogue after standard got to app page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made a facebook php webapp, I am using the following code to make facebook redirect to the "got to app" permissions page

```
   $params = array(
   scope => 'publish_stream,user_likes',
   redirect_uri => 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage/480192585363812?sk=app_23508216934343'
   );
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
   echo "<script>
   window.top.location = '$loginUrl';
   </script>";
```

This works fine and takes me to the page correctly, however when I click on "got to app", then facebook displays a second dialog, the URL is

```
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request
```

How do I prevent the second page and allow the user to authorise the app in one click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining this into one single click/dialog (like "authorize!") is purposefully not possible.

**Explanation:**

`user_likes` is a `Extended Profile Property` and  `publish_stream` is a `Extended Permission`. They are not authorized at the same time, because extended properties are a "Non-optional permissions for access to a user's data and that of their friends." whereas users can opt out of an extended permission